# GDAL 2.1.3 doesn't have LIBKML

Tags: gdal, libkml

My System (Ubuntu) previously had GDAL 1.11.2. We have an issue with using `ogr2ogr` converting KML to SHP in that the attributes were missing. In researching this, it seems that the LIBKML driver should fix this. I have tried researching various questions and tutorials on getting the LIBKML driver to work but I never seemed to get it working.

I have seen in other places that the LIBKML driver comes with GDAL in version 1.9.2 onwards. I got GDAL 2.1.3 on my system now, (verified with `gdal-config --version`), however when I run `ogrinfo --formats`, it is still only showing back KML and not both KML and LIBKML.

Is the LIBKML driver supposed to come with GDAL 2.1.3 out of the box?

**Update:**

As per request, here is the output from `apt-cache policy gdal-bin`

```
gdal-bin:
  Installed: 2.1.0+dfsg-1~trusty2
  Candidate: 2.1.0+dfsg-1~trusty2
  Version table:
*** 2.1.0+dfsg-1~trusty2 0
       100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
    1.10.1+dfsg-5ubuntu1 0
       500 http://mirror.rackspace.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

**Update with Solution**
I downloaded `gdal` in a weird way, as pointed out by @AndreJ
Everytime I would uninstall everything, then reinstall the package, it still kept coming up with version 2.1.3 which isn't available through the PPA, which apparently doesn't have LIBKML.

What I had to do was manually `locate gdal` and `locate kml` and `rm` any and all files and instances found. After everything was gone, I could install gdal again and version 2.1.0 was installed with the LIBKML driver.

Comment: On Fedora it comes with KML driver: ogrinfo --formats | grep -i kml
  LIBKML -vector- (rw+v): Keyhole Markup Language (LIBKML)
  KML -vector- (rw+v): Keyhole Markup Language (KML)
... 
[neteler@oboe r.seasons]$ rpm -qf /usr/bin/ogrinfo 
gdal-2.1.2-5.fc25.x86_64
So it seems to depend on the packaging in the respective Linux distro.

Comment: Please include the result of `apt-cache policy gdal-bin` to your question to see from where you got GDAL.

Comment: @AndreJ check updated post

Comment: But that's GDAL 2.1.0, not 2.1.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have updated GDAL in an unusual way. GDAL 2.1.0 is available for trusty from the ubuntugis unstable ppa. After adding the ppa to your sources and updating gdal-bin, you should get the following output:

```
 $ ogrinfo --version
 GDAL 2.1.0, released 2016/04/25
 $ ogrinfo --formats | grep -i kml
 LIBKML -vector- (rw+v): Keyhole Markup Language (LIBKML)
 KML -vector- (rw+v): Keyhole Markup Language (KML)
 $ apt-cache policy gdal-bin
 gdal-bin:
   Installiert:           2.1.0+dfsg-1~trusty2
   Installationskandidat: 2.1.0+dfsg-1~trusty2
   Versionstabelle:
  *** 2.1.0+dfsg-1~trusty2 0
         500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
         100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
      1.10.1+dfsg-5ubuntu1 0
         500 http://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

which clearly states LIBKML support for this GDAL package.

---

**Update from comments**

You have tried compiling GDAL 2.1.3 from source. This installs binaries in local folders where they can not be removed by dpkg or apt.

Instead, you have to carefully inspect the installation steps to see where the files are copied to, or which folders are included in search paths like `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Delete those self-compiled files, and make sure no gdal command can be found, **before** doing a clean install from packages.

Comment: Honestly I'm not too fluent in this so I was trying a bunch of different methods. One way I did use was the PPA, `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa && sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install gdal-bin` which was how I "thought" I got version 2.1.3. 

When I run `ogrinfo --version` it goes give me `GDAL 2.1.3, released 2017/20/01` though.

So I'm not sure where I went wrong or how to fix it.

Comment: The method you describe is how to add ubuntugis **stable** ppa, but that has also package gdal 2.1.0+dfsg-1~trusty2. You must have another version (maybe self-compiled or self-extracted) with version number 2.1.3, which is only available for Debian experimental according to https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/gdal. You better remove all GDAL, including that version, before reinstalling from ubuntugis.

Comment: I've tried to remove it, but the version number of `2.1.3` still shows up when I type `gdal-config --version` and `ogrinfo --version`. I may have to start a new thread on this in the Ubuntu.SE, but do you have any suggestions on how I should completely remove gdal? I have `--purge remove` everything with gdal and kml in the `dpkg --get-selections` and `apt-get list` and gdal still seems to be installed on my system.

Comment: If you have compiled anything from source, dpkg and apt will not catch and remove those libs. But go ahead on Ask Ubuntu about it. I always use packages only.

Comment: ogrinfo from packages is in `/usr/bin/ogrinfo`, while your self-compiled version is in `/usr/local/bin/ogrinfo`, and will not get deleted by any dpkg or apt command.

Comment: Correct all of the gdal files are in `/usr/local/bin`, so how would I go about uninstalling a self-compiled version then?

Comment: Would it be as simple as just deleting all of those binary files in the `/usr/local/bin/` directory?

Comment: Just go ahead, you will not get lucky with them. You might need sudo privileges.

Comment: I have removed the old version. Removed the stable PPA. Added the unstable PPA. Downloaded gdal-bin, and I still have 2.1.3 without libkml

Comment: I guess there is still something self-compiled left in `$HOME/gdal-compile/bin` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Before downloading any packages, make sure that `type ogrinfo` returns something like `not found`.

Comment: Yeah I did that before which is when I thought it was fixed, but you're right there was still something left behind. I had to `locate` and `rm` any and all instances of `gdal` and `kml` and it finally worked. Thank you for all your help!